# How to correctly convert letters to numbers?

Tags: c#, ascii

I have a string which comprise lots of letters. I have used the following code to convert it to numbers, but the new string **t** still gives me imperfect result.
For example:

> tung2003 -> -1-1-1-12003
>
> **What I expected:** 1161171101032003 (116 is the ASCII code of **t**, 117 is the ASCII code of **u**

```
string t=null;
foreach (char c in Properties.Settings.Default.password)
{
      int ascii = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(c);
      int counter=0;
      counter = ascii;
      t = t + Convert.ToString(counter);
}
```

The problem is the **-** character. I want my new string only comprises numbers.

Comment: How should `tung2003` be converted to `1-1-1-12003`? I can´t see any logic here.

Comment: @HimBromBeere How can I know? The problem is in my codes

Comment: So what you wrote above is what you get. But what do you *expect* instead?

Comment: What is your desired result? What do you expect the letter 't' or 'u' to be after your conversion?

Comment: "Return Value
Type: System.Double

The numeric value of c _if that character represents a number;_ **otherwise, -1.0.**" From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7k33ktz(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Looks to me like Char.GetNumericValue may be returning -1.

Comment: Look at my edited post, I have added what I expect

Comment: The ASCII values of numbers are not the actual numbers though.  For example, your expected output ends in `2003` but the ASCII value of "2003" would be `50484851`

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you do *not* want the ASCII values of the numbers based on your expected output.  In that case you can just do something like this:

```
string input = "tung2003";

string output = string.Empty;

foreach(char c in input)
{
    if(char.IsNumber(c))
    {
        output += c;
    }
    else
    {
        output += ((byte)c).ToString();
    }           
}
//output is now: 1161171101032003
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5lnr1w)

Answer (score 1):

Also added as a Linq expression for a short hand solution.

```
        // Method 1 Linq
        string output = string.Concat(("tung2003".ToCharArray()
            .Select(s=> char.IsDigit(s) ? s.ToString() : ((int)s).ToString())));

        // Method 2
        string input = "tung2003";
        string output = string.Empty;

        foreach (char c in input)
        {
            if (Char.IsDigit(c)) output += c.ToString();
            else output += ((int)c).ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Extrapolating your output it looks like you want two different things. You want to tally each ascii character as long as it is a letter and extract the numeric values to append. The following provides three options, the first is to tally the ascii values from letters and the other two are ways to extract only digits. Because your code example uses a Password I am assuming you are trying to do some sort of custom hashing and if that is the case you should use a Hash implementation from the Cryptography namespace or some other package.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var combined = OnlyLettersToAscii("tung2003") + OnlyNumbers("tung2003");

            Console.WriteLine($"Input: tung2003 Output: {OnlyNumbers("tung2003")}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Input: tung2003 Output Regex: {OnlyNumbersWithRegex("tung2003")}");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static string OnlyLettersToAscii(string originalString)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(originalString)) return originalString;

            return string.Join(string.Empty, originalString.ToArray()
                .Where(w => char.IsLetter(w))
                .Select(s => ((int)s).ToString()));
        }

        private static string OnlyNumbers(string originalString)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(originalString)) return originalString;

            return new string(originalString.Where(w => char.IsDigit(w)).ToArray());
        }

        public static string OnlyNumbersWithRegex(string originalString)
        {
            return Regex.Replace(originalString, @"[^\d]", string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string t = "";
foreach (char c in Properties.Settings.Default.password)
{
      if (IsNumber(x)) t += System.Convert.ToInt32(c).ToString();
      else
      {
          t += c.ToString();
      }
}
```

Moreover, if you just want to get rid off '-' the use this code: `t =String.Replace(t, '-');`

Comment: This will give the output `11611711010350484851` which is **not** want the OP wants.